# PHP JQUERY AJAX PAGINATION

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm just looking for some advice in this post.
I am currently using pagination via a $_GET variable in the url. However I am not paginating by first calculating a count and then using a LIMIT clause. Instead I am retrieving all values to paginate, then placing them in an array which is then sliced, so the first 10 items of the array are displayed on the first page, and the next 10 on the second page, etc. There is a reason for this madness.

However, this results in the entire query running every time a user clicks a different page number.

Is it at all possible to instead use jQuery/AJAX, so that I can run the query once, then simply cycle through the array without having to reload the page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please see [this link](http://www.nacodes.com/2013/03/14/Pagination-with-Jquery-PHP-Ajax-and-MySQL) it's very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you have to get everything out in your query anyway you might as well divide everything up into pages in one go and put them on your page ready to be hidden/shown. Then your page links/buttons will just need to hide the current page and show the page clicked. Shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Just a side question, 
What do you think would be more efficient for pagination?
Running a large (possibly huge)query to retrieve all "articles" (for example) then using jquery to cycle through, OR
running smaller queries per page. So the first page would run a query for 10 "articles" then the second page would run for the second 10 articles. So a query would run on each new page of the pagination

Comment: I think it would depend on the amount of data you have. If it's a lot, then it's definitely better to do smaller queries, one for each page of the pagination. If there's a lot of data and you're loading it all at once, there'll be a long wait for the data to be sent back to the calling AJAX function. It's a trade off really.. depending on the size of your data, loading it all will have a longer delay to begin with but near instant page switching whereas, loading 10 at a time would mean little initial delay but very slightly longer delay switching pages. Personally I'd go for the 10 at a time.